# MySQL query for top documents based on associated tags

Tags: mysql, sql

There is  a list of documents. Multiple  users can tag document. Now for  given tags (more tha, list of  documents is required where more than 30% of users have chosen  that tag.

```
mapping:
---------------------------  
user_id | document_id | tag
    1   |     34      | 26
    2   |     34      | 26
    3   |     36      | 25 
    4   |     34      | 27
```

A helper table is also there with total tag_count for given document.

```
counters:
---------------------------  
document_id | tag_count
    34      | 12
    36      | 26
```

I am able to write query for single tag like

```
select * from mapping m
join (select document_id,count(*) as req_tag_count
from mapping
group by document_id) as s on s.document_id = m.document_id
join counters c on c.document_id = m.document_id and req_tag_count / c.tag_count > .3
where m.tag = 26
```

But not able to write query for multiple tags like **return documents with both tags A and B fulfilling the above condition of 30%.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
SELECT t.document_id
FROM (SELECT m.document_id
    FROM mapping m
    WHERE m.tag = 26         # Specify the first tag
    GROUP BY m.document_id
    HAVING COUNT(m.document_id) /
    (SELECT count(document_id)
        FROM mapping i
        WHERE i.document_id = m.document_id
        GROUP BY i.document_id) > 0.3
    UNION SELECT n.document_id
    FROM mapping n
    WHERE n.tag = 27         # Specify the second tag
    GROUP BY n.document_id
    HAVING COUNT(n.document_id) /
    (SELECT count(document_id)
        FROM mapping i
        WHERE i.document_id = n.document_id
        GROUP BY i.document_id) > 0.3)
AS t
GROUP BY t.document_id
HAVING COUNT(t.document_id) = 2    # One per tag
```

It worked when I tested it. You can adapt this for 3 tags as well.

Comment: How does this query work for 2 tags ? i mean document with both tags 'A' and 'B' > .3

Comment: @Terminal You wrote you wanted documents listed for a given tag. Maybe you mean for a given document you want to list those tags that more than 30% of users selected?

Comment: I have mentioned in last line that i am able to get list of documents for a given tag but not for list of tag. I will edit the question to make it more clear